# Render multiple React Native components efficiently with predefined priority

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Let's say I have `N` components of same type (will assume N=5 for simplicity). Let's say each one of them has a priority given with the array `[3, 1, 2, 4, 5]` (higher number = higher priority). What would be an elegant and efficient way to render them with the specified order? So firstly would like to render the last element (`priority = 5`), then the one with `priority = 4` and at the end the 2nd element (with `priority = 1`).

I don't want to re-render the components which have already been rendered. For instance, once the component with `priority = 5` is rendered, it shouldn't be re-rendered, thus I shouldn't change its state.

My real problem is bigger than this, I actually have swiping views. I want to render firstly the current view and after that its neighbours. What I am interested in is a more general advise how to give priority to the rendering of different components.

So, the actual prototype I am looking for is:

```
 1. at the beginning the screen is empty
 2. 5th element appears (priority = 5)
 3. 4th element appears (priority = 4)
 4. 1st element appears (priority = 3)
 5. 3rd element appears (priority = 2)
 6. 2nd element appears (priority = 1)
```

In each step only the new view should be rendered. Is this possible?